# Initialization of std::array with std::initializer_list in constructor's initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, initializer-list, stdarray

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct foo {
  std::vector<int> v;
  foo(std::initializer_list<int> L) : v{L} {}
};
```

The code above compiles fine and initializes `v` as expected. Now consider the following piece of code:

```
struct bar {
  std::array<int, 3> a;
  bar(std::initializer_list<int> L) : a{L} {}
};
```

The above piece of code gives a compile error.

> error: no viable conversion from 'std::initializer_list' to 'int'

Searching the web I found that the "proper" way to initialize a member `std::array` with a `std::list_initializer` is to use `reinterpret_cast` in the following manner:

```
bar(std::initializer_list<int> L) : a(reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3> const&>(*(L.begin()))) {}
```

### Q:

Why I can initialize a member `std::vector` with an `std::initializer_list` in the initialization list of a constructor but I can't a member `std::array`?

Is the work-around showed above with `reinterpret_cast` the proper way to initialize a member `std::array` with a `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have any constructors besides what the compiler gives it.

Comment: The cast is dangerous because the initializer list may contain fewer items than the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::array` was [designed (in the Boost library)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/array.html) to support the braces initialization syntax with C++03. The only way to do that in C++03 was as a POD (plain old data) type, one with no constructors. Initializer lists were introduced in C++11, along with `std::array`, but `std::array` was not changed from its Boost version to use initializer lists. So, it's historical.

By the way, note that the `reinterpret_cast` is dangerous here because the initializer list may contain fewer items than the `array`.

Answer (score 1):

a `std::array` is a thin wrapper around a C++ array, see it like

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct {
  T data[N];
}
```

So it doesn't have any constructor able to cope with a `std::initializer_list`, you must stick with a `vector` or copy the elements with something else (like `std::copy`) in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> foo(std::initializer_list<int> L) : v{L} {}
> ```

`std::vector` has a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list` as input.  You are thus initializing the vector itself, not any particular element of the `std::vector`.

> ```
> bar(std::initializer_list<int> L) : a{L} {}
> ```

`std::array` does not have a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list` as input (in fact, it does not have any constructors at all, it can only be initialized through [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)).  You are thus trying to initialize a specific element of the array, which is why the compiler complains that it cannot convert a `std::initializer_list` to an `int`.